# Redirecting to site from an existing button being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm quite new to coding. I have a button with the ID='test'. I want to run a line of code in javascript or HTML to redirect users to a site when that button is clicked.

Button:

```
<button id="test" type="submit" onclick="setNick(document.getElementById('nick').value); return false; return false" class="btn btn-play-guest btn-success btn-needs-server primaryButton" data-itr="play_as_guest">
```

I tried running this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("test").onclick = window.location='http://www.google.com/' 
</script>
```

However, this would redirect straight away. I want it to redirect only when the button is clicked. Please help me fix this.

Many thanks.

Comment: `onclick` should be a function

Comment: @PriyeshKumar Could you please elaborate. I'm a coding beginner, so I'm not sure how. Do I do function() or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the redirect to the button where you need to assign it to a function.

You can try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){ 
     window.location='http://www.google.com/';
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works but it just refreshes the page. I made an edit, please refer to the question, I've added the code for the button.

Comment: The button is redirecting to google.com not refreshing. Do you want it to open a new window? If so, I would then use `window.open('http://www.google.com');` instead

Comment: I will capture my problem with as a GIF

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use onclick on button, for example

your button will look like this

> `<button id="test" onclick="redirect()">Redirect</button>`

Now in the script write the redirect function as

```
<script>
  function redirect() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, this works but it just refreshes the page. I made an edit, please refer to the question, I've added the code for the button.

Comment: To make it more clear can you create a plunker with the problem you are having

Comment: I've edited the question, added the code for the button.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are doing there, you have onclick function as setNick right, you can have this redirect line also in that function itself, so that you don't need to write document.getElementById("test").onclick

Comment: Do I set the nick ID to redirect?

Comment: It is quite confusing, what I understand from the code you provided is you want to redirect to a page when clicked on that button. Now from the code I am seeing that there is a function called serNick with a argument, what is that for and you want to redirect after that function or you want to replace that function?

Comment: I have another field box where the user enters text and then that name gets setNick when the play button is clicked, I would like to replace this function Sri

Comment: Does that make sense? @Sri

Comment: No, we need a plunker or something explaining the problem correctly, otherwise it's not possible to provide you with correct answer, also separate your functional requirement from the question you have to make it easier for others to understand

Comment: Ill upload it in plunker, please bare with me for a minute